# Performance and Optimization - Too many bootstrap modals

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I am building a table based on data returned from my API.
For each row in the table I would like to create a bootstrap modal with additional info in it.

This is how I do it right now. I created a designated div and I put all the modals inside it. Please note that in addition the modal's HTML is pretty big by itself:

```
let modal = `<div id="modal-${i}">big HTML here</div>`;
$("#modalsCollector").append(modal);
```

And this is how my table row looks like:

```
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-${i}">
```

Because I sometimes have 500+ table rows there is eventually a huge div (#modalsCollector) full of same (by structure) modals. I feel that it affects page performance.

Is there a better, more elegant and performance optimized way to bind modals to table rows? Or in general, working with many hidden elements instead of pushing them into the DOM that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include only one "null" `modal` in your `<body>`, like this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then when you have to show the modal generate it using jQuery like this:

```
    $("#button").click(function(e){
        $("#myModal .modal-header").append(HTML for modal header here);
        $("#myModal .modal-body").html(big HTML for modal body here);
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    });
```

So, basically you change the modal header and the modal body of the *same* modal each time, with the needed information accordingly, without the need of like thousands of modals.

Comment: I thought about this idea but $("#button").click() does not have modal data to display. Or I am missing something?

Comment: @vogliamoci yes $("#button").click() does not have modal data by itself. You have to use a function to return the data you need to populate your modal with. The button is clicked -> you get the data you need -> you fill the modal with this data >- you show the modal to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a neat way of changing the components of the same modal. This is as long as you need the same modal just different content inside.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fta">Open modal for @fat</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // Update the modal's content. 
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in future it would be helpful, if you could provide a minimum working example (as little code as possible) to demonstrate your solution.